# Swift4.2 parse json for use in pickerview

Tags: json, swift4.2

I'm trying to populate a `UIPickerView` using the response from an API, I can successfully do this with basic JSON responses but I am really struggling with the example below where the JSON returns a value as an array.

The code below is from a Playground and has been simplified to only show the relevant code, I am confident that if I can create a variable with the array in the correct format then I can use it to populate the `UIPickerView` but I've included the `UIPickerView` code in case I am going about this the wrong way.

I have searched for and tried to adapt various examples from both this forum and others but for some reason, I just can't get it to work, I am new to Swift so I'm on a learning curve!

The closest I have got is `account(data: ["account1", "account2", "account3"])` but I need to get `["account1", "account2", "account3"]`

I hope someone can help and hopefully not downvote the question.

```
import UIKit

let json = """
{
"returnResult":1,
"data":["account1", "account2", "account3"]
}
"""

struct account: Codable {
    var data: [String]
}

let accounts: account = try JSONDecoder().decode(account.self, from:json.data(using: .utf8)!)

print(accounts)

/*
RESULT RETURNED
account(data: ["account1", "account2", "account3"])

RESULT REQUIRED
["account1", "account2", "account3"]

PICKERVIEW CODE FROM WORKING VIEW

// picker view methods
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent    component: Int) -> Int {
return accs.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int,    forComponent component: Int) -> account? {
return accs[row]
}

// delegate method
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
let selectedDriver = accs[row]
displayLbl.text = selectedDriver
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it sorted using the following code as the basis for the solution

```
import UIKit

struct Account: Codable {
    var data: [String]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet private var displayLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    // MARK: - Internal Variables'
    var account: Account?

    // MARK: - IBActions
    @IBAction private func showPicker(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        pickerView.isHidden = !sender.isSelected
    }

    private func createAccountList() {
        let json = """
        {
        "returnResult":1,
        "data":["account1", "account2", "account3","account4", "account5", "account6"]
        }
        """
        do {
            account = try JSONDecoder().decode(Account.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    private func initUI() {
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createAccountList()
        initUI()
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return account?.data.count ?? 0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return account?.data[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        displayLabel.text = account?.data[row]
    }
}
```

The project can be found on Github https://github.com/techmehra/uipicker-demo

I did have to amend the code slightly to make it work with the live API response.